# ensure class member variables are not modified when cloning

Tags: c++

I am trying to add a clone func for class A. This class has a non const and not owned pointer b_. I want to make sure that b_ wont be modified in the cloned objects, but it is ok to modify other member variables, and these non-const func in A can still be called.

A bad way is adding a flag and check it every time before modifying b_. It is bad because if a new func in A is added, some one else might forget to check it.

Is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Here is my bad solution mentioned above:

```
class A {
 public:
  A* clone() const {
    auto* clone = new A(*this);
    clone->is_cloned_ = true;
    return clone;
  }
  void DoSomething() {
    if (!is_cloned_){
      b_->NonConstFunc();
    }
  }

  void DoSomethingElse() {
    other_values = 2; // cloned versions can modify this.
  }
 private:
  is_cloned_ = false;
  B* b_; // Not owned
  int other_values = 1;
}
```

Comment: Updated my question. Added constraints: 1. non-const functions in A should still be callable 2. other member variables are still modifiable in the cloned version.

Comment: My first impression is that your design is off. Why can a non-cloned object choose to point to something new, but a cloned object cannot? It's not exactly a clone when it has reduced functionality (which reads to me like there should be another class in the picture).

Comment: I agree that it is not an ideal design. Feel like it is a "shortcut" for a solution if I can find a ideal way to implement this, but I just cant find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps design a class hierarchy like this:

```
class cloned_A;

class A
{
public:
    cloned_A *clone ();    
private:
    B* b_;
};

class cloned_A : public A
{
public:
    cloned_A (const B *b) : read_only_b (b) {}
private:
    const B* read_only_b;
};

cloned_A *A::clone ()
{
    return new cloned_A (b_);
}
```

Now `b_` is private to `A` and the cloned object can only access `read_only_b` via a `const` pointer and therefore cannot modify it.

Comment: I like the basic idea. But it is too easy to accidentally get `A` from a `cloned_A` and thus accidentally modify the `B` object. Example: If you pass `cloned_A` to a function that takes a reference to an `A` you have accidentally removed your constness.

Comment: @MartinYork Would doing this make any difference?  `b_` is private to `A` so can only be accessed by methods of `A` anyway, so the 'contract' (whatever that is) remains in force.

Answer (score 0):

A way to avoid issue when adding method to `A` is to wrap the logic to access `B` in its own class:

```
class ProtectedB
{
public:
    ProtectedB(B& b) : b(&b) {}
    ProtectedB(const ProtectedB& rhs) : b(rhs.b), cloned(true) {}

    // Duplicate public B interface
    void NonConstFunc() {
        if (cloned){ return; }
        b->NonConstFunc();
    }

   // Possibly (might avoid to duplicate non mutable interface of B)
   const B& GetB() const { return *b; };
private:
    B* b = nullptr;
    bool cloned = false;
};
```

Then `A` is simply:

```
class A {
public:
    // ...

    std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const { return std::make_unique<A>(*this); }
    void DoSomething() { b.NonConstFunc(); }
    void DoSomethingElse() { other_values = 2; } // cloned versions can modify this.

private:
    ProtectedB b;
    int other_values = 1;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I think people might still forget to add that check in the new ProtectedB class when adding something new. . Maybe my design is just a bad design.

Comment: `ProtectedB` has only one purpose, and is simply to update. Most probable mistake would be to not add new function from `B` inside it, (no error, just lack of functionality). Then if A need that missing function, it is trivial to add back. And I agree that your design is questionable.